# how to use bind_rows with tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I am trying to use bind_rows and tibble from tidyverse, and getting unexpected results.

When I combine several data frames with `bind_rows` and then transform them to a `tibble`, the column names get messed up:

```
library(tidyr)
pred.models <- c('1.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv')
prediction.slides <- list()
for (modelid in pred.models){
  tmp <- read.csv(modelid)
  tmp[,'modelid'] <- modelid
  prediction.slides[[length(prediction.slides)+1]] <- (tmp)
}

prediction.slides <- (bind_rows(prediction.slides))
typeof(prediction.slides)
# -> list
# now let's see what we got:
prediction.slides
# -> `bind_rows(prediction.slides)`$hash      $class_prob $modelid
```

However, when I try following:

```
pred.models <- c('1.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv')
prediction.slides <- list()
for (modelid in pred.models){
  tmp <- read.csv(modelid)
  tmp[,'modelid'] <- modelid
  ############################################  Changed here:
  prediction.slides[[length(prediction.slides)+1]] <- tibble(tmp)
}

prediction.slides <- (bind_rows(prediction.slides))
```

I am getting an error `Error: Argument 1 can't be a list containing data frames` on the last line.  Which is very strange given that `bind_rows` is for combining list of data frames according to the docs.

Any idea how to do it correctly and get a nice tibble as output?

UPD: csv files look like following:

```
hash,class_prob
1578d8,0.9451976000
1c7644,0.4519760001
dc7358,0.5197600012
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the csv files are supposed to look like?

Comment: @Phil see update

Comment: Would `library(tidyverse); prediction.slides <- map_dfr(c("1.csv", "2.csv", "3.csv"), read_csv)` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `tibble()` doesn't do what you think it does. You need `as_tibble()` instead. `tibble()` is used to construct data.frames from given inputs, while `as_tibble()` transforms the input into a tibble, which is what you want.

Comment: that's an anti-intuitive design decision, but seems to solve it!